# Regex start with exactly two alphabetic characters and than followed by any digits

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm trying to create a very simple regex that accepts strings:

1. starts with two [A-Za-z] characters
2. ends with any number of digits

my code is:

```cs
Regex.IsMatch("AA00000000000", $"^[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]*$")
```

but it returns False. Where am I wrong? I've already tested the same regex with the same input on [regexstorm.net](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5bA-Za-z%5d%7b2%7d%5b0-9%5d*%24&i=AA00000000000) and it works.

Comment: Why do you have `$` before the regular expression pattern string (i.e. 2nd parameter) ?

Comment: Sorry, Wiktor is going to mark your question duplicate.

Comment: Thank you, the error was the ```$``` in front of the string.

Comment: @LeonardoLurci, no, the error was not escaping `{` and `}` in [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated), like this `Regex.IsMatch("AA00000000000", $"^[A-Za-z]{{2}}[0-9]*$")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working for me with below code:

```
string pattern = @"^[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]*$";
string str = "AA00000000000";
bool val = Regex.IsMatch(str, pattern);
```

Answer (score 1):

You put a "$" in front of your regular expression, because of that the "{2}" part will be interpreted as just "2", so the regex that gets evaluated looks like this: "^[A-Za-z]2[0-9]*$".

Answer (score 1):

Regex.IsMatch method return boolean value. Please, try with this way. You can also try with using "$"

Comment: I think you lost a part of your answer, is it right?